# Compiling as 16-bit (for ms-dos) with visual studio

Tags: compiler-construction, dos

Is this possible? If it is, how?
And if not, which compiler that does allow that do you recommend?

Thanks!

Comment: Compiling what? C, assembler, VB etc...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I seem to remember that Visual C 1.52c was the last version that would generate 16-bit code.

There's been quite a bit of water under the bridge since then.

You can probably still pick up Turbo Pascal 3 or Turbo C 2 from the [Borland museum](http://edn.embarcadero.com/museum/) - I don't care whether they call themselves Inprise or Enchilada or whatever, they will *always* be Borland to those who used and loved their products :-)

I'm not sure if DJGPP (based on gcc) will generate 16-bit code. I vaguely recall it comes with a DOS extender which may mean it generates 32-bit code. I may be wrong. There was also something called egcs (from memory) that you may want to look into.

You can also check out [OpenWatcom](http://openwatcom.org/index.php/Detailed_Contents), they appear to do 16-bit DOS among others. Watcom was a respected name alongside Borland back in the day.

Comment: I think C7 is also available somewhere on the msdn.

Comment: As MASM cannot generate 16-bit code, what's the rational for maintaining the `SEGMENTS` directive in the language?